# Prevent double click on HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to prevent my users from double clicking on submit button.
Can some one tell me how to prevent it for
 & 
in HTML

Comment: Use `.one()` if you only want the event to trigger once or define a flag that prevents a submit button click until the previous click has been processed (validation, ajax etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to prevent an action when a user double clicks, use the `.dblclick()` function.

```
$("submit").dblclick(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you're trying to make it so that a form is only submitted the first time the button is pressed, then use the `.one()` function somewhat like this:

```
$("submit").one("click", function(){$("#yourformid").submit();$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");});
```